# Updating Home URL in WordPress on AWS EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have a WordPress instance (Bitnami) on an EC2 instance, and the site is currently accessible by IP address or Public DNS. Additionally, we have the actual domain name pointing to the site using Route53.

My current issue is that the WordPress home/site URL is still set to the public DNS address, which means, the site can be accessed by the domain name, however when clicking around the links, the URL switches to the public DNS address.

My goal is to ensure that the WordPress address becomes the actual domain name, not the public DNS address.

I have attempted a search & replace in PHPMYADMIN, however doing so, made no change on the actual site. In WordPress Settings, the Home URL and Site URL still show the public DNS address, and all menu links still show the public DNS address in the href.

Anyone have experience with this to point me in the right direction ? am I missing anything here ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress v3.3.1-5 or higher, only specify your domain name in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php` file. Edit and replace the following lines as shown, remembering to replace the DOMAIN placeholder with the actual domain name you wish to use:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

with

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://DOMAIN/');                   
define('WP_HOME', 'http://DOMAIN/');
```